# Use ASP ScriptingContext Request collections in C#?

Tags: c#, com

I am trying to use request elements from an ASP application in a .NET class library that is used in the application. I came across a head scratcher that I can't wrap my head around:

```
//Context is an ASPTypeLibrary.ScriptingContext
dynamic req = System.EnterpriseServices.ContextUtil.GetNamedProperty("Request");
Context.Response.Write(req.Form("mykey")); //this writes the value I expected
Context.Response.Write(String.Format("{0}", req.Form("mykey")));  //this writes 'System.__ComObject'
```

Am I going about this all wrong? I was using info I gleaned from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10321652/how-to-set-scriptingcontext-response-cookie-after-upgrade-to-net).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should note that `Request.Form("someKey")` is not a `string`. The source of your confusion, however, originates not in `Request.Form("someKey")` but on the other side, in `Response.Write(...)`.

There are some automatic conversion shenanigans going on.

`Request.Write(...)` doesn't take a `string`. It takes a `Variant`. The method will do its darnest to output whatever you pass to it.

If the `Variant` holds a `BSTR` (a COM string), it will output that unchanged. It will also try calling `VarChangeTypeEx(...)` (kind-of; see note below) to try to see if it can get COM to convert it to a `BSTR` (that's what happens when you pass it a number). If the `Variant` contains an object with a default method on it ([propvalue]), and it has no better way to output it, it will call the default method and start over with the result of that. I think it has a few other tricks up its sleeve, which are not entirely clearly documented.

At a high level, it should now be clear what's happening. On the first line, `req.Form("myKey")` returns a COM object, which then gets passed down to `Response.Write(...)`, which then converts that object to a `BSTR` string and outputs it. On the other hand, when you try to pass `req.Form("myKey")` to a C# method, the conversion doesn't occur and you get a generic COM object instead, with predictable consequences.

So what is the return value of `Request.Form("someKey")` then? It's an [`IRequestDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524456%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) object. And why a dictionary? Because you can submit an http request that has multiple form elements with the same name. This can be the case, for example, when the input elements are checkboxes intended to be overlapping options.

What happens when the form has multiple entries? The conversion process returns a joined string analog to `String.Join(", ", someArray)` in C#.

It's not clear to me whether `Response.Write` has intimate knowledge of `IRequestDictionary` (unlikely), or whether it knows about COM Enumerator pattern (more likely) and it enumerates them to compose the string.

More interesting to me is who is responsible for the conversion process, because VBScript's `CStr()` will do the same conversion. I had always assumed that `CStr()` was a thin wrapper around `VarChangeTypeEx(...)`, but I'm pretty sure that `VarChangeTypeEx(...)` does not concatenate enumerators like that. Obviously `CStr()` is a lot fancier than I had assumed. I believe that Response.Write simply calls internally whatever API fully implements `CStr()` and relies on that for the conversion.

For further exploration of the Classic ASP objects and interface, try [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524856(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524856%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) instead of the usual VBScript-based descriptions.

Comment: Thank you, the answer is as simple as adding the index, and you don't even have to cast it to another type, you can just do `Context.Request.Form["mykey"][1]` (or loop through it, etc)